# How to access other component props. (React)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Thinking that I have a component:

```
    <Component1>
        <Component2 value={0}/>
        {window.console.log(Component2.value)}
    </Component1>
```

How may I do this window.console.log works, because I have a problem trying to reach that prop.

Comment: I think you should read more the [react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). It's not how you should access values from Components. If you want to log the value, you should put your `console.log` into your `Component2`.

Comment: You will be passing the `prop` i.e '0' from `Component1` to `Component2`.
You already have access to it.

Comment: The value of component2 changes inside it and it is just an figured example. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you access that value from the state of the `component1`?

```
class Component1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    };
    this.incrementCounter = this.incrementCounter.bind(this);

  }


  incrementCounter() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ counter: prevState.counter + 1 }));
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Component2
          incrementCounter={this.incrementCounter}
          counter={this.state.counter} />
        <Component3 counter={this.state.counter} />
      </View>
    )

  }
}
```

Lastly inside the Component2

```
<button onClick={this.props.incrementCounter}>
  click to increment counter
</button>
```

This is number one rule of the React, child components doesn't mutate data
 they speak to parent component through methods passed to them. This also makes data flow better, actually this is how you should be using React.

Comment: Because it changes inside the component2.

Comment: The value in the state is reactive, means if it changes in Component2 it will also update Component3. So it's not a valid argument

Comment: I think that you didn't understand, I have the first component that passes a state to the second component, that state is the initial value of the second component. But inside of the second component this value changes because it is a counter, after all the process that occurs inside the second component I have to read the response of it, I need to read the new value of Component2.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to do is pass to your `<Component2>` a callback function as a `prop` that returns the value updated to your `<Component1>` (I've made a little StackBlitz => https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rym9h9?file=Component2.js), here you have the sample:

`<Component1>:`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Component2 from './Component2';
import './style.css';

class Component1 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  getUpdatedValue = (updatedValue) => {
    console.log('Here is your updated value: ', updatedValue);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Component2 value={0} returnUpdatedValue={this.getUpdatedValue} />
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<Component1 />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

`<Component2>:`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Component2 extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { value, returnUpdatedValue } = this.props;
    let updateValue = value + 100;


    returnUpdatedValue(updateValue)
  };

  render() {
    const { value } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
      <h1>{value}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Component2;
```